# Trying to get row position correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I currently [have a question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437680/get-row-position-of-count-of-distinct-rows) but I don't think it's receiving the attention it deserves, probably because of its extension and editions throughout the time. With this one I'll try to be as concise as I possibly can, lets go!

I am trying to get the row position of a specific table, in this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40ed4/1)

I currently have 2 queries on it: one that lists all rows ordering them by column rank (which is a COUNT() of other rows); and other that gets the info for a specific row.

In this screenshot of the SQLFiddle, I have the current results, and in yellow (right next to the position column) I have the desired result. You can see that "position" is probably referring to column id, not to column rank, as it should be:

[image: Current results / Desired result (in yellow)]

**How can I achieve the desired result?**

In case Fiddle doesn't loads, here's all the DLLs:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;

INSERT INTO `site_users` (`id`, `username`) VALUES
(1, 'Mateus'),
(2, 'Marco'),
(3, 'John'),
(4, 'Luke'),
(5, 'Wall');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `site_articles_comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;

INSERT INTO `site_articles_comments` (`id`, `user_id`, `data`, `comment`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1492101324, 'Too good to be true'),
(2, 1, 1492101392, 'It\'s so, not very.'),
(3, 1, 1492106262, 'I loved it!'),
(4, 3, 1492107619, 'Seems fishy'),
(5, 1, 1492108002, 'Don\'t blame it on her'),
(6, 2, 1492108433, 'As I highly doubt it'),
(7, 2, 1492200402, 'This is just a test'),
(8, 2, 1492267629, 'Another test'),
(9, 2, 1492267684, 'No sht'),
(10, 4, 1492267766, 'WTF?'),
(11, 2, 1492267796, 'Pics, pleaseee!');
```

Test queries:

```
/* This simply order users on rank (rank being number of comments) */
/* This query tries to get the row position of user based on rank */

SELECT x.id,
       x.username,
       x.rank,
       x.position
  FROM (SELECT u.id,
               u.username,
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position,
               (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(c.id)),0) AS rank
                  FROM site_articles_comments c
                  WHERE u.id = c.user_id ORDER BY rank DESC) AS rank
          FROM site_users u
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
        ORDER BY rank DESC) x;

/* Based on the list above, user (Marco) should have a position number of 1 */

SELECT x.id,
       x.username,
       x.rank,
       x.position
  FROM (SELECT u.id,
               u.username,
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position,
               (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(c.id)),0) AS rank
                  FROM site_articles_comments c
                  WHERE u.id = c.user_id ORDER BY rank DESC) AS rank
          FROM site_users u
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
        ORDER BY rank DESC) x
  WHERE x.id = 2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get row position of COUNT() of distinct rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43437680/get-row-position-of-count-of-distinct-rows)

Comment: Do not ask the same question twice, no matter what's the reason.

Comment: Ok, then I deleted the original question.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for might be this:

```
SET @rowno2=0;

SELECT x.id,
       x.username,
       x.rank,
       x.position,
       @rowno2:=@rowno2+1 AS rowno
  FROM (SELECT u.id,
               u.username,
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position,
               (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(c.id)),0) AS rank
                  FROM site_articles_comments c
                  WHERE u.id = c.user_id ORDER BY rank DESC) AS rank
          FROM site_users u
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
        ORDER BY rank DESC) x;

SET @rowno2=0;

SELECT x.id,
       x.username,
       x.rank,
       x.position,
       @rowno2:=@rowno2+1 AS rowno
  FROM (SELECT u.id,
               u.username,
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position,
               (SELECT COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT(c.id)),0) AS rank
                  FROM site_articles_comments c
                  WHERE u.id = c.user_id ORDER BY rank DESC) AS rank
          FROM site_users u
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
        ORDER BY rank DESC) x
  WHERE x.id = 2
```

So you can use a MySQL variable to keep track of the row number.

I haven't looked at the rest of your SQL.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, that's not entirely what I am trying to do. Rowno is giving me accurate results in the first query, but in the second it just returns "1" as it's just one row. But the desired result is to have it returning the Rowno of the equivalent user in the first query: [link](http://image.prntscr.com/image/385eca4637954ec1bae214b3fd01a73d.png)

Comment: I see what you mean. You are using PHP, so you could use that. From the first query you get the relation between `id` and `rowno`. You can make an array like so: `$array[$id] = $rowNo`. You can use that array while reporting on the second query. If you only want to use MySQL you could store the data in a temporary table.

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine this done by php, but I don't see this being right in terms of performance if, for instance, I have to look for a position of a user in a table with 100k+ rows. I thought it would be interesting to see a solution only using MySQL, one that shows the row number (position in rank) of a specific user.